# Bugs in login code

Tags: java, debugging, authentication

As you might have guessed, I have a small bug in my login code. It's not major, and it won't effect much, but it would be more professional if I got it figured out. I've spent the last 48 hours trying to figure out the code, and I know it's going to be something super simple and easy to figure out for the pros here. But. Here is my code.

```
class loginButton implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("Username".equalsIgnoreCase(textUsername.getText()))
            if ("Password".equalsIgnoreCase(textPassword.getText())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Success.");
            CowboyCorral success = new CowboyCorral();
            success.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed.");
            }
        }
    buttonLogin.addActionListener(new loginButton());
```

In this code, as you can see, if my username is 'username' and password is 'password' (super secure) then it gives you the prompt 'login success' and it disposes the window and opens the second file in my project. That works all dandy.

But the problem is, if the entered credentials is *wrong* it won't display the 'login failed' prompt.

Again, it may be a simple solution, and I promise I'll feel bad, but I'm still learning and would love someone to take a look at it and tell me where I messed up. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I understand the problem. Lets check one or two thing before I post an answer : Can you try entering incorrect username and see if Login Failed dialog gets displayed. I hope it will be displayed.

Comment: Just double checked, won't display.

Comment: Can you do textUsername.getText().toString() in place of textUsername.getText() for both username and password

Comment: Program function doesn't change. Can still login but 'login failed' is not displayed.

Comment: Update : If my username field is correct, but my password field is incorrect, it will actually display the 'login failed' prompt. I may have figured it out...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Alok :D Have a nice night :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Here's my changes : I changed

```
if ("Username".equalsIgnoreCase(textUsername.getText()))
        if ("Password".equalsIgnoreCase(textPassword.getText())) {
```

to

```
if ("Username".equalsIgnoreCase(textUsername.getText()) && ("Password".equalsIgnoreCase(textPassword.getPassword().toString()))) {
```

and since the two checks, instead of one being after the other, it checks them at the same time. What was happening is that it would say 'yes, your username is correct. is your password correct? If not, THEN I will display your login has failed. Now it will check both of them at the same time, and return the part of the code depending on what is entered.

Comment: This was the second thing that I was about to make you do. Thanks